# Managing user points on Q&A site

Tags: php, mysql, points

I am making a question and answers site kind of like Yahoo Answers. It is going to have a points system where users can vote on answers, but I don't know if I should remove points that a user earned on a topic if it is deleted (and add points back that were removed if they got any down votes). This leads onto my main question: what would be the best way to do this?

I made a `points` table and whenever a user earns points it is logged in the `points` table and then it is added/subtracted from the total on the `users` table.

But, if a question is deleted how would I manage to subtract the points that were earned (and add points back that were lost with down votes)?

The structure of my `points` table is (I just did a `SHOW CREATE TABLE points` query):

```
CREATE TABLE `points` (
 `pid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `point_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `question_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `timestamp` int(25) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`pid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

And the `users` table:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `fname` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `lname` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `username` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `password` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `confirm_key` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `email` varchar(80) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `user_pic` varchar(300) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `user_title` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `moderator` varchar(5) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'false',
 `deleted` varchar(4) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no',
 `suspended` varchar(4) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no',
 `points_count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

I just don't know if it's a good idea to remove/give back the points gained/lost on a question if it gets deleted.

I know that Stack Overflow does this but they have a much more advanced system.

Comment: Although irrelevant to your question, I would personally make the datatype of `deleted` and `suspended` fields **DATETIME** instead. Much easier to track and gives more info :) Otherwise for boolean values **TINYINT** would be a better choice: 0 or 1. It would consume less space and it would be faster.

Comment: @inhan Thank you for that info... I always wondered what TINYINT does. If it consumes less space, I'm all for it. :)

Comment: How do you relate your users to the points table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the user should still be rewarded for the time spent sending the post.  Also a user should still be "punished" if your user group thinks that the answer deserves to be down-voted. Remember a point system in answer/question sites are a determining factor in such sites.

Having said that if you still intend to return/take the points to/from the users that earned the points on the deleted post this is the way to do it in SQL

```
SELECT u.user_id, SUM(//points awarded)
FROM points p
JOIN users u ON p.point_user = u.user_id
Group By p.point_user
```

Comment: Yeah I forgot about the points column in the users table - I was just about to add it. Also it is kind of confusing to people that didn't make it but the `point_user` column is actually the user's ID that is being given the points, and I see you used `.SUM` so I assume that adds something together? I'm editing my SQL above with another column.

Comment: It is actually SUM(), I made a typo.  Basically SUM is a function that adds all the given rows together.  You would most likely have to Group by the user id in the query as you will end up with a number of rows that will have a repeated SUM.

Comment: Ah, I see. So you mean `Group By u.user_id` right? _(edit: actually never mind I see what you mean)_ I'm gonna try all of these answers (including yours) and see which one works best.

Answer (score 1):

My thinking is that just because of an administrative change, the person that took the time to answer the question still earned it...just my opinion - I could be wrong.

Comment: Yeah I see your point. I won't be doing question voting, at least for now (I'm too lazy right now to make that feature too lol) but yeah I think that it's a good idea to keep the points, but what about if the answerer deletes their answer? The points should probably be removed and the down vote points should be returned, right?

Comment: It's all very subjective - I've had points lost because "someone" decides the question isn't "good" enough, or some such thing, but on the other hand, answering the same question over and over is counter productive - I just don't think it's as simple as delete/lose points is all.

Answer (score 1):

I would make the return points in case of a deletion.

On your `users` I would recommend two changes:

```
`moderator` tinyint(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`deleted` tinyint(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`suspended` tinyint(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
```

I think `tinyint` is better than `varchar` in this case.

And I would also add on your `points` table the `id` of the `user` that +1/-1 the question so you can track the user when you need to give the points back.

Comment: That's a good idea, never thought of that. I'll add a column that holds the id of the user that voted, and I will also change those to `tinyint` as you said since it's just a 0 or 1. Thanks for the recommendations. I still don't know _how_ I can give/take the points back... add all the points earned from the points table for that specific question maybe? Hmm this is more challenging than I originally thought it would be.

Comment: You will have a function that will update the question status, setting it to deleted for instance, that happening you will check the `points` table for the `question_id` and get all the `ids` from the users that voted and make a loop on those `ids` and update the `users` table, returning those points....I'm saying it without thinking too much so just accept the idea and try to evolve it =)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove points when a question is deleted, one way I can think of to do this is to use a [database trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/triggers.html).

You can have a trigger fire when a DELETE statement is executed on the `points` table, and then update the `users` table with the appropriate recalculation, ensuring that the `total` column in the `users` table is correct.

For the question on whether or not it is "logical" to modify a user's points if a question is deleted, that is your preference, as you're the one implementing the logic of the site. :)